# How do I create ajax functions for the whole site?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am creating a notification center, naturally it must be visible throughout the site; So the question is how do I do it.
Create a `name.js` file inside the `static` folder but it seems that something is missing since apart from the delay in the `app` itself it is not visible outside it.

view.py

```py
@csrf_exempt
def NewsSubjects(request):
    if request.is_ajax() == True:
        queryset = Downloads.objects.all().order_by('register_date').values()[:5]
        data=list(queryset)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

urls.py

```py
path('alerts/', views.NewsSubjects, name='alerts'),
```

/static/js/notifications.js

```js
$.ajax({
    // initialize an AJAX request      
    url: "alerts",
    // al estar en static no se usa el name del URL ('control:alert') sino el PATH (alerts/)
    type: "GET",
    datatype:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('cambio')
        var opciones = document.getElementById("nuevasDisciplinas");
        var countAlert = document.getElementById("countAlert");
        var listaDisciplinas = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // console.log(data[i]);
            var nombDis = data[i].category_name
            var fechaCreacion = data[i].register_date
            // var d = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(fechaCreacion)
            // var m = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(fechaCreacion)
            // var a = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(fechaCreacion)
            var icon = '<divclass="mr-3"><divclass="icon-circle bg-primary"><iclass="fas fa-file-alt text-white"></i></div></div>'
            var body ='<div><divclass="small text-gray-500">'+fechaCreacion+'</div><spanclass="font-weight-bold">'+nombDis+'</span></div>'
            listaDisciplinas += icon+body
        }
        opciones.innerHTML = listaDisciplinas;
        countAlert.innerHTML = data.length;
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("The information could not be obtained");
    }
});
```

master.html

```html
<script src="{% static 'js/notifications.js' %}"></script>
```

the idea is simple, bring the latest records according to the date of registration (the best option would be the login date to the system but good), **this works** in the notification app but not in the rest.
It returns the message that I put in case of error.

PS: if you can lend me a hand with the formatting of the date it would be fine too

Comment: Why is it "Create `name.js` inside the static folder" then "`/static/js/notifications.js`" then `"{% static 'js/graficas_control.js' %}"`? Can you please clarify the file name

Comment: @crimsonpython24 a confusion of libraries, so any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use the `path` of the **url** instead of the name, that is, the name of the `app/url/`

Django the `urls.py` they consist of `path(this_url, view, name_url)` so to use it throughout the Django site you must use `app/this_url/`

in my case

my urls.py

```py
path('alerts/', views.NewsSubjects, name='alerts'),
```

in the ajax url it would be

```py
$.ajax({
    url: "app_name/alerts/",
    ...
});
```